# SQL Keep running count, after inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I am working with a local mysql server and I have two tables.

**Table A:**

```
ID | Name 
1    Joe
2    Bob
3    John
```

**Table B:**

```
ID |    DATE    |  Name_ID | Point
1    2010-01-01       1       1
2    2011-01-01       1       1
3    2013-01-01       1      -1
4    2010-01-01       2      -1
5    2012-01-01       2      -1
6    2013-01-01       2      -1
7    2014-01-01       2       1
```

For each ID in Table A, I am trying to get the

1. max date and
2. a running count of their points. (dates and points being in Table B).

**Wanted Result:**

```
Name | Latest_Date | Point_total
John      NULL         NULL
Joe     2013-01-01      1
Bob     2014-01-01     -2
```

So far I Have this Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name, b.Date, SUM(b.point) OVER (PARTITION BY b.Name_ID) Point_total FROM 
TableA a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB b 
ON a.ID = b.Name_ID 
INNER JOIN  (
SELECT b.Name_ID, MAX(b.Date) Latest_Date 
FROM TableB b GROUP BY b.Name_ID ) m 
ON (m.Latest_Date = b.Date or (b.Date is NULL)) AND 
(b.Name_ID = m.Name_ID OR (b.Name_ID is NULL)) 
ORDER BY Name_ID;
```

The resulting table does output the correct max date, but the running total only takes into account the point of the entry with the max date.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with a "running total".

Answer (score 2):

This just looks like aggregation:

```
SELECT a.Name, MAX(b.Date), SUM(b.point) as Point_total
FROM TableA a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TableB b 
     ON a.ID = b.Name_ID 
GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 2):

That's an aggregation query:

```
select a.name, max(b.date) latest_date, sum(b.point) point_total
from a
left join b on b.name_id = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.Name, MAX(B.Date) as Max_Date, SUM(b.point) as Total_Points
FROM TableA as A
    LEFT JOIN TableB as B 
    ON A.ID = B.Name_ID 
GROUP BY A.name
```